# Calculating Datediff from nested json sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to use `datediff()` to find the age of a person in a postgres db (from their date of birth(. I know I  can run `datediff()` like this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(current_date, '2021-01-24');
```

The query i use to get date of birth is (its  in json)

```
select date_of_birth from (select attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth' from users) as date_of_birth;
```

This gives me output like

```
date_of_birth      
--------------
 (2000-11-03)
 (2000-06-11)
 (2000-05-31)
 (2008-11-26)
 (2007-11-09)
 (2020-03-26)
 (2018-06-30)
```

I tried using

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(current_date, (select date_of_birth from (select attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth' as date_of_birth from users));
```

It doesn't work. I tried several permutations but i can't get it to work.
How should I edit my query to calculate the user age?

Comment: Thanks, I am still struggling to get the right query though with the `-`. I also tried `age()` . Not good with nested queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query:

```
select date_of_birth 
from (
  select attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth' 
from users
) as date_of_birth;
```

Returns the *row* rather than a column, (the column expression for the extracted date value has no defined alias). It's like using `select users from users`. You need to make `date_of_birth_ a **column alias** (not a table alias) and use that in the outer query.

To get the difference between two dates, [just subtract them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) but you need to cast the valued to a `date` to be able to do that.

```
select current_date - u.date_of_birth 
from (
  select (attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth')::date as date_of_birth
  from users
) as u;
```

Or without a derived table:

```
select current_date - (u.attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth')::date
from users as u
```

Apparently your dates are stored in a non-standard format. In that case you can't use as cast, but you need to use the `to_date()` function:

```
to_date(u.attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth', 'mm:dd:yyyy')
```

---

If you are storing JSON in the `attrs` column you should convert it from a `text` (or `varchar` column to a proper `json` (or better `jsonb`)  so you don't need to cast it all the time.

Comment: Thanks - i get an error message though - `ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "02:21:2020"` with both those queries.

Comment: @Illusionist: well, that's obviously a wrong date format, that you can't just cast to a date - if you are using such a non-standard format, then why did you show ISO formatted dates as your sample data?

Comment: Ahh i see some fields are null. Maybe that's what is causing the issue. I did not change the format of dates.

Comment: The error message in your comment clearly states that at least one row contains `02:21:2020` as the date value

Comment: Ahh you are absolutely right, thanks. I tried updating it  `update users set attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth'='02-21-2020' where attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth'='02:21:2020'` but its erroring out `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"`

Comment: I have a mix of formats so to_date(u.attrs::json->'info'->>'date_of_birth', 'mm:dd:yyyy')
doesn't work becausei t errors out like `ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2020-11-03"`